# Remove Sender name ( not email address) from outgoing Mac Mail

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

Instead of "from" showing (Name,Name)blablabla@hjgy.xxx  -  just show   blablabla@hjgy.xxx.

Only want my email address to show on certain outgoing emails from certain servives, ex. show Name and email address from Verizon service but (no name) email address only when sent from Gmail service.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Mail (menu) > Preferences... > Accounts > select the target account and under Account Information in the Full Name: field put the email address not the full name.